# New install of Python always gives the error "Python Shell, prompt [x], line [x] builtins.NameError: name '[function]' is not defined

Tags: installation, shell, python, development

I am new to coding, and I just installed Python 3.7.1 and Wing IDE Personal 6.1 on my computer. I installed python first, then Wing IDE, and pointed Wing to python.exe through the project properties menu. Here's what shows up in the python shell when I start Wing IDE:

```
3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)]
Python Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I wrote the following program:

```
def addFive(value):
    return 5 + value
```

Then saved and ran the program. I wrote in the shell "addFive(106)" and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 3, line 1
builtins.NameError: name 'addFive' is not defined.
```

I took some code that I wrote on a school computer, where it ran as intended, and tried to run it on my home computer, where I received the same error. I tried multiple different simple functions. What's going on? Did I install Wing IDE/Python wrong? I know these programs work, so there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the program file so that python could find the function? Python can't find code buried in some random file, even if it's in the current directory.

Type

> import filename

where filename is the name of the file containing the function,  without the .py suffix. That loads the file into the interactive session.

Comment: When I tried that, I got the following error:
 `import tester
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 7, line 1
builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tester'`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and I'm posting here in case anyone else has this problem and stumbles upon this post. I had to go to the "options" dropdown just above the python shell and select "evaluate [filename]". The line ">>>[evaluate [filename]]" appeared in the python shell, then I could run my program.